# Communication protocols between Java and C

Tags: java, c, communication

I wrote a server application in C and a client application in Java for android, I'm using byte streaming to communicate. How can I improve this communication protocol? Is there a cross platform communication protocol, like JSON, using structs?

Comment: Communication protocol is different from data transfer format. JSON is sort of data transfer API, not a communication protocol.

Comment: @iUngi - when you say "byte streaming", do you mean TCP sockets? What does your app do? what is the goal of the improvements you are looking for? Performance? Interoperability? Agility?

Comment: Yes, I'm communicating through TCP socket. I would like to control my quadcopter with my android phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use TCP as a communication protocol.

I would use a text format such as JSon as a data format using UTF-8 character encoding.

I would make the API as simple as possible.